# Jquery Tr Selection Object wrong length - Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

Ok so I use the following jquery selector + length attribute to get the current number of visible rows in a table:

```
$('#orderable tbody tr:visible').length
```

This works magnificently in Chrome (v. 13.0.782.220 m), but is wrong in Safari (v. 5.0.5) (both webkit... I find this baffling.)

I grabbed the selector object and logged it in the console to see what it was getting, and in Safari, the last 4 rows of my table are present in the selector object **twice**, and I have no idea why. The table itself does not show these extra 4 rows, nor are they hidden anywhere weird on the page when I view the HTML in the console.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? I'm not sure I've ever seen Safari and Chrome behave differently before... FWIW, the length property is correct in Firefox and IE

Oh and this is all being tested on Windows 7, however my boss informed me of this bug on Safari on Mac as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any difference if you use the direct descendant selector style?

```
$('#orderable > tbody > tr:visible').length
```